# All rails commands returning identical error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an odd error, where no rails commands of any kind are executing. Whenever I enter a rails command I get the following:

Ignoring racc-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.5.2

(this is repeated about 100 times before the following):

`` bin/rails:2:in `load': /Users/robertmorris/Desktop/All Projects/Code School/my9s/bin/spring:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) rescue Gem::LoadError ^ /Users/robertmorris/Desktop/All Projects/Code School/my9s/bin/spring:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input from bin/rails:2:in `<main>' ``

My bin/spring file:

```
if !defined?(Spring) && [nil, "development", "test"].include?(ENV["RAILS_ENV"])
  gem "bundler"
  require "bundler"

  # Load Spring without loading other gems in the Gemfile, for speed.
  Bundler.locked_gems&.specs&.find { |spec| spec.name == "spring" }&.tap do |spring|
    Gem.use_paths Gem.dir, Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path
    gem "spring", spring.version
    require "spring/binstub"
  rescue Gem::LoadError
    # Ignore when Spring is not installed.
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old (unsupported) version of ruby.

You should upgrade it using any available local version manager like `rvm`, `rbenv` or `asdf`, to at least 2.5, or better 2.7 or 3.

---

On ruby 2.4 and previous, you could only rescue inside either a method:

```rb
def foo
  # do something
rescue
  # do something else
end
```

or an explicit `begin`/`end` block:

```rb
begin
  # do something
rescue
  # do something else
end
```

Since ruby 2.5 was released, all `do`/`end` blocks can have `rescue` clauses:

```rb
foo.bar.baz.tap do
  # do something
rescue
  # do something else
end
```

while before that you had to

```rb
foo.bar.baz.tap do
  begin
    # do something
  rescue
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: So the answer is to update Ruby to at least 2.5. A couple of days ago Rails 7.0 alpha was released which requires at least Ruby 2.7. Therefore I would suggest updating to Ruby 2.7 or even better 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @spickermann, I will make the answer clearer